# Different output coming when using param observable

Tags: angular

I have used the following two code snippets to get the value of editmode variable in the console according to my routes.I think both should works the same. But the first one is giving the right output and the second one is always showing true.Can't figure out whats wrong here

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-recipe-edit',
  templateUrl: './recipe-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recipe-edit.component.css']
})
export class RecipeEditComponent implements OnInit {
  id:number;
  editMode:boolean=false;
  constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(
        (params:Params) =>{
            this.id = +params['id'];
            this.editmode = (params['id'] != null);
            console.log(this.editmode);
        }
    );
  }

}


import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-recipe-edit',
  templateUrl: './recipe-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recipe-edit.component.css']
})
export class RecipeEditComponent implements OnInit {
  id:number;
  editMode:boolean=false;
  constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(
        (params:Params) =>{
            this.id = +params['id'];
            this.editmode = (this.id != null);
            console.log(this.editmode);
        }
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: `params['id']` will be a `string` or `undefined`. It will never be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

This was more like, find the difference between the two. I bet that the `params['id']` is not a `number` or `numberic` and doing a `+param['id']` will give you `NaN` which is not equal to `null`.

In your first code, if you will do the following change, you will get the same output you are getting in the second one.

```
 this.route.params.subscribe(
    (params:Params) =>{
        this.id = +params['id'];
        this.editmode = (+params['id'] != null);  // change here
        console.log(this.editmode);
    }
);
```